# R Programming using "dplyr" to select rows and return the index of the rows found

Tags: r, dplyr

## Setup/Problem:

Using dplyr - I cannot determine the optimum way to return the row index of a filtered row as opposed to returning the content of the filtered row.

## Issue:

I can use dplyr::filter() to extract the row from the dataframe... the issue is that want to extract the index value of the filtered row and add it to a list of index entries that meet the search criteria.

## Question:

Is there a simple way to search a dataframe using dplyr against specific criteria and return the numeric index of each row found? The code below uses r::which() to extract the index rows to a list...

```
    requiredPackages <- c("dplyr")

    ipak <- function(pkg){
            new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
            if (length(new.pkg))
                    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
            sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
    }

    ipak(requiredPackages)

    if (!file.exists("./week3/data")) {
            dir.create("./week3/data")
    }

    # CSV Download
    if (!file.exists("./week3/data/americancommunitySurvey.csv")) {
            fileUrl <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
            download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./week3/data/americancommunitySurvey.csv", method = "curl")
    }

    housingData <- tbl_df(read.csv("./week3/data/americancommunitySurvey.csv"
                                   , stringsAsFactors = TRUE))

 Now we have to extract the relevant data
#
# Create a logical vector that identifies the households on greater than 10
# acres who sold more than $10,000 worth of agriculture products. Assign that
# logical vector to the variable agricultureLogical. Apply the which() function
# like this to identify the rows of the data frame where the logical vector is
# TRUE. which(agricultureLogical) What are the first 3 values that result?
#
# ACR 1
# Lot size
# b .N/A (GQ/not a one-family house or mobile home)
# 1 .House on less than one acre
# 2 .House on one to less than ten acres
# 3 .House on ten or more acres                 ACR == 3
#
# AGS 1
# Sales of Agriculture Products
# b .N/A (less than 1 acre/GQ/vacant/
#                 .2 or more units in structure)
# 1 .None
# 2 .$ 1 - $ 999
# 3 .$ 1000 - $ 2499
# 4 .$ 2500 - $ 4999
# 5 .$ 5000 - $ 9999
# 6 .$10000+                                    AGS == 6
#
# Thus, we need to select only the results that have a ACR == 3 AND a AGS == 6
#
agricultureLogical <- which(housingData$ACR == 3 & housingData$AGS == 6)
agricultureLogical
# Now we can display the first three values of the resulting list
head(agricultureLogical[1:3])
```

The above code gives me the result I want but I want to understand how to do this with dplyr. It is bugging me... I can use dplyr::filter() as follows to extract the rows lines - how do I extract the index of each row found????

```
agricultureLogical <- filter(housingData, ACR == 3 & housingData$AGS == 6)
```

## R Setup

version
               _
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin13.4.0
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0
status
major          3
minor          1.2
year           2014
month          10
day            31
svn rev        66913
language       R
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet

dplyr version  0.3.0.2

## Setup Mac OS X

Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro10,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.7 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Memory:   16 GB

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a dplyr function specifically for this, but you could probably use a logical subset of `1:n()`

Comment: Richard - thanks for the post - can you provide a little more information?

Comment: Perhaps something like `do(mtcars, data.frame(x = which(.$cyl == 4)))` as an example with the `mtcars` data set and looking for which rows contain cylinder equal to 4.  You can add `%>% .$x` after the call to get a vector instead of a `data.frame` if you choose

Comment: If you have such a simple vectorized solution why use `dplyr`?

Comment: David Arenburg - it is unclear to me how to return the index of the row in a dataframe using dplyr. I would like to know how to do that.

I understand how to do this with R::which()

Essentially, I am searching through a dataframe using dplyr against a set of criteria and rather than return the row data I want to return the index of the row. 

I could not see how to do that with dplyr hence the question. I know how to do it using which as per the code.

Comment: perhaps using `with()` can help if your objective is to write less times your data.frame's names. `with(which(ACR == 3 & AGS == 6))`. I normally use `data.table` for this type of operations that already has a call to `with` by default.

Comment: Plus one from me; I'm in a similar situation. Attempting to get an index for the rows returned after using `group_by` in `dplyr`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using dplyr >= 0.4 you can do the following

```
housingData %>%
  add_rownames() %>%
  filter(ACR == 3 & AGS == 6) %>%
  `[[`("rowname") %>%
  as.numeric() -> agricultureLogical
```

Though why you would consider this an improvement over

```
agricultureLogical <- which(housingData$ACR == 3 & housingData$AGS == 6)
```

escapes me.

Comment: Ista, I don't see it as superior I am just trying to determine how to use the dplyr package more optimally. i.e. How can you return the index offset number as opposed to the row data.

Comment: dplyr is preferable, especially with large datasets, because it is optimized to run faster

Comment: @Servet usually claims that one method is faster than another are backed up by benchmarks. Care to offer one?

Comment: A starting point could be http://datascience.la/dplyr-and-a-very-basic-benchmark/

Comment: @Servet I don't see what that blog post has to do with this question. dplyr may be faster for some things, but this question is about extracting row numbers meeting some criteria.

Comment: Although I love dplyr, I must admit @Ista has a point here: The which() solution is much more elegant...

Comment: [Roberto notes that add_rownames() is deprecated in favor of ronames_to_column()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434411/1048186).

Comment: @Ista I realized I never accepted your answer. That for your guidance, it was and remains appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

## Proposed Solution

Here is an example of what I am trying to do... this is sort of a solution but I do not like it. Thanks for to Richard Scriven for the pointer to 1:n()...

## Add an index column to the dataframe manually...

I have still not figured out how to return individual index numbers for each of the rows that match a particular set of criteria...

So I added an index column to the example data frame using **dplyr:mutate()**. I then use **dplyr::filter()** on the data-frame to apply a filter against the required criteria. This leaves me with the list of rows I want to play with... including an index to the original data frame... I now use **dplyr::select()** to extract only the index column of the original dataframe entries for each row that meets the criteria...

```
h1 <- housingData
# Add an index column to the dataframe h1...
h1 <- mutate(h1, IDX = 1:n())
# Filter the h1 dataframe using the criteria defined...
h1 <- filter(h1, ACR == 3 & housingData$AGS == 6)
# Extract the index 
h1 <- select(h1, IDX)
# Convert to an integer list...
agricultureLogical <- as.integer(as.character(h1$IDX))
head(agricultureLogical[1:3])
```

the above to me is duplicated effort as the index is implicit in the origional dataframe. Hence my sense is there must be a way to return the set of indexes of the items identified by the filter... Answers appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4):

As add_rownames() is deprecated you can use rownames_to_column(). The Ista's solution will be in the following format:

```
housingData %>%
rownames_to_column() %>%
filter(ACR == 3 & AGS == 6) %>%
`[[`("rowname") %>%
as.numeric() -> agricultureLogical
```

Comment: I needed to install the tidyverse package to get the rownames_to_column() function.  install.packages("tidyverse"), then library(tidyverse).

Comment: There is also a rowid_to_column() that might automatically be numeric so that `as.numeric` might not be required. (Also in tidyverse)

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution would be to use `with` wrapped around `which`:

`agricultureLogical <- housingData %>% with(which(ACR == 3 & AGS == 6))`

Answer (score 2):

```
housingData %>%
  mutate(test = ACR == 3 & AGS == 6) %>%
  pull(test) %>%
  which
```